# Push in my javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, push, jslink

I need some help for my JSlink code.

I used this code, it work well:

```
var Fields = {
    "Continent": {
            "NewForm": FieldTemplate,
            "EditForm": FieldTemplate
    },
    "Country": {
            "NewForm": FieldTemplate,
            "EditForm": FieldTemplate
    },
    "City": {
            "NewForm": FieldTemplate,
            "EditForm": FieldTemplate
    }
};
```

But I would like to make it dynamic so I tried this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++){
    Fields.push(fields[i].name: {
        "NewForm": countryFieldTemplate,
         "EditForm": continentFieldTemplate
    });
}
```

In the for loop, fields is an array who contains "Continent", "Country" and "City" but my code don't work and I want to know why.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: we need more code. How does your fields array look like? where do you initialize countryFieldTemplate etc.?

Comment: `Fields ` is not an array but rather an object. so you better use `for in` loop

Comment: `push` is a method of `Array`, whereas `Fields` is a plain object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create properties on a JavaScript object using the syntax:

```
Object[propertyName] = propertyValue;
```

So this should work:

```
var Fields = {};
for (var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++){
    Fields[fields[i]] = {
        "NewForm": countryFieldTemplate,
         "EditForm": continentFieldTemplate
    };
}
```

Where `fields` is:

```
var fields = ["Continent", "Country", "City"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Fields needs to be an object rather than an array
var Fields = {};

// loop over your fields array
for (var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++){

    // then just assign each field as the key to the Fields object
    Fields[fields[i]] = {
       NewForm: countryFieldTemplate,
       EditForm: continentFieldTemplate
    };
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ajyf8x9u/)